# Throw exception in cucumber stepdefs

Tags: java, junit, cucumber-jvm

I'd like to implement cucumber stepdefs for connexion with database. And I'd like to test the case of exception thrown by doa (SqlException). how can we simulate sqlexception when calling Dao?

```
  @Given("The data base calling return sqlexception$")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
private boolean throwSqlException = false;

@Given("The data base calling return sqlexception$")
public void returnsSqlExcception() {
    throwSqlException = true;
}

@When("do something")
public void doSomething() {
    if(throwSqlException) {
        throw new SqlException();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The sqlException should be thrown in the dao class not stepdefs class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock the DAO. This is not the part of cucumber. Keywords to google: EasyMock, Mockito, JMock.

Will be something like

```
@Given("The data base calling return sqlexception$")
public void sqlExceptionThrownOnDbCall() {
    expect(mockedDao.methodToBecalled(...)).andThrow(new SqlException()); 
}
```